# Difference between Java's || and & operator

Tags: java

In Java, the & operator evaluates both the operands and so does the || operator.

I do understand the difference between && (AND) and || (OR) operators. I want to gain some understanding on bitwise & operators and the logical || operator.

What is the difference between them? Which one to use when?

Comment: Do you mean `&` or `&&`?

Comment: And are you trying to tell us that you don't know the difference between Boolean AND and Boolean OR?

Comment: A && B ---> Both A and B have to be True. A || B --> A or B needs to be True

Comment: @HotLicks Actually, unless the OP wrote it wrong, `&` is a bitwise operator, as pointed out in the possible duplicate given by @Purag.

Comment: @tomasyany - Correct.  There were so many things wrong with Opie's question that it would take a small book to respond completely.

Comment: The question is still unclear; you're asking about the differences between two *completely different* operators. (They're not even in the same category of operators). What differences are you curious about?

Comment: @Purag - I have never used bitwise operators and was wondering what are possible scenarios where they could be used. After reading some online material it looks like bitwise operators operate only on int and long datatypes. It helps to know how integers are represented in binary.

Comment: Yes; they are "bitwise" because they modify the bits that make up a number. They can be used on any data type, as long as that data type can be safely cast to an `int` or `long`. Many people prefer to use `long`s for bit operations, though.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in something called "short circuiting".

The & and | operators always evaluate both sides of the operands.
The && and || operators "short circuits" the operation by not evaluating the right operands if it isn't necessary.

Comment: And what about the fact that `&` and `|` are bitwise operators, and `&&` and `||` are logical operators?

Comment: Ok. Maybe I need to be more specific. What I mean is when `&` and `|` is used as logical operators